# Move the CKEditor inline toolbar

Tags: position, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 4 inline. Is it possible to change the toolbar location e.g. 50px over the editor div?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep this "floating toolbar" behaviour, then you can move it around using [these settings](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-floatSpaceDockedOffsetX).

But if you want to keep toolbar in one place, then check this plugin: http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace

There's a sample, but you need to build a CKEditor package with this plugin and then you'll be able to check it.

Comment: Ok, now it works, thank you Reinmar. Maybe someone would have a look to my Demo: http://jsbin.com/azuqif/8/watch

Comment: If it works, then you should accept the answer ;) PS. We uploaded all plugins' samples on ckeditor.com site - here's one for [sharedspace](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/sharedspace/sharedspace.html).

Comment: "these settings" link is broken.

Comment: WFM. But if you're checking on mobile it may not work, because there were some problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply give `margin-top: -50px;` to the toolbar element if you want to place it 50px over the editor div.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Harish, I've found a way to make it work for **CKEditor 5: Inline Editor**. This is how to move the toolbar relatively from its current position.

```
.ck.ck-toolbar-container {
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-left: 48px;
}
```